# Increasing Rank of a homogeneous linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} a^1_1 & a^1_2 & \cdots & a^1_d \\ a^2_1 & a^2_1 & \cdots & a^2_d \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \ & \vdots \\ a^d_1 & a^d_2 & \cdots & a^d_d \end{pmatrix}$$ be a square matrix of dimension $d$ and rank $r$ which satisfies the homogeneous linear system

$$Ax = 0.$$

If we say that the rows of $A$ are such that not all entries of each are equal, that is; if $a_i$ is a row of A, then there is exists no constant $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \begin{pmatrix} 1&1& \cdots &1\end{pmatrix} = a_i$ for all $i$, is it true that the rank of $\tilde{A}$ is $r+1$ where

$$\tilde{A} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1& \cdots & 1\\ a^1_1 & a^1_2 & \cdots & a^1_d \\ a^2_1 & a^2_1 & \cdots & a^2_d \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \ & \vdots \\ a^d_1 & a^d_2 & \cdots & a^d_d \end{pmatrix}?$$

I'm not sure how I would go about this other than just pure intuition. This condition I mention on the rows of $A$ would ensure that no row operation could completely eliminate any row of $\tilde{A}$ using this new row we introduced on the top that we couldn't already eliminate in $A$ before.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say that the matrix "satisfies the homogeneous linear system". For every matrix $A$, $Ax = 0$ has a solution.

Comment: Also, note that your matrix $\tilde A$ has size $(d + 1) \times d$, which means that it's rank is at most equal to $d$ (i.e. the rank will never be $d+1$). Did you mean to say that the rank of $\tilde A$ is $r+1$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean satisfies the system with nullity$(A) > 0$ , i.e. has more than just the trivial solution (so in particular det$(A) = 0$. Also, yeah to your second comment - it should indeed be $r$, so thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. As an example, consider the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1}, \quad \tilde A = \pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1}.
$$
$A$ has no constant rows, but $A$ and $\tilde A$ both have rank $2$.

Comment: Thank you! Good counter-example.

Comment: A slightly more aesthetically pleasing counterexample:
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9}
$$